# store user input in an array and display on screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, input, display

Storing info in an array(firstName, lastName, accNumber, etc). I already have some data in array. I want to ask user input and push that input in array and save it as well as display it on screen(not in console). Also new info is not saving in the array. I use prompt as well as form . from is not working.

```
/* creatting array  */
        var customer = [
            {fname: "Jhon", lname: "Yojin", accNo: 1, balance: 400},
            {fname: "Jane", lname: "Jin", accNo: 2, balance: 500},
            {fname: "Emily", lname: "Sena", accNo: 5, balance: 100}
        ];
        console.log(customer.length);
        console.log(customer[1].fname);
        console.log(customer[2].lname);
        var newName = prompt("what is your lnamename?");
        customer.push(newName);
        console.log(customer);

    /*function to add data in array*/    
    function addInArray() {
        var  addName = document.getElementById("#nameInput");
        customer.push(addName.value);
        addName.value = "";
        console.log(customer);

    } 
     /* display array*/
    function displayArray(){
        for(var i=0; i < customer.lenght; i++){
            document.write("customer" + i + customer[i] + "</br>");
            document.getElementById("#showName").innerHTML = customer[i];
        }
    }    
    </script>

    <form>
        <input id="nameInput" type="text"/ placeholder="yourInfo">
        <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addInArray();">Add </button>
        <button type="button" id="myList" onclick="displayArray();">Display</button>
    </form>  
        <div id="box"></div> 
        <div id="showName"> </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `for(var i=0; i < customer.lenght;` <= is this a typo in the source code or just the question?

Comment: It is a part of code to display each element of an array.

Comment: Right, but `lenght` is a typo.  It should be `length`, thus me asking if you typed it wrong only here, or if it is like that in your actual code.

Comment: you are right ! length is typo. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't write `#` while you are using `getElementById`

```js
/* creatting array  */
var customer = [
    {fname: "Jhon", lname: "Yojin", accNo: 1, balance: 400},
    {fname: "Jane", lname: "Jin", accNo: 2, balance: 500},
    {fname: "Emily", lname: "Sena", accNo: 5, balance: 100}
];

displayMyAcc()
function displayMyAcc(){ 
var myAccNo = prompt("what is your acc number?");
document.getElementById("showName").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(customer.filter(x=>x.accNo==myAccNo)[0]);
}

/*function to add data in array*/    
function addInArray() {
  var  addName = document.getElementById("nameInput");
  customer.push(addName.value);
  addName.value = "";

} 
/* display array*/
function displayArray(){
  for(var i=0; i < customer.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("showName").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(customer[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="nameInput" type="text"/ placeholder="yourInfo">
    <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addInArray();">Add </button>
    <button type="button" id="myList" onclick="displayArray();">Display</button>
</form>  
<div id="box"></div> 
<div id="showName"> </div>
```

Comment: Trying to ask user accNumber as a input and comparing it with array acc. number and display it . Only specific acc number details and not whole array.

Comment: function displayMyAcc(){
    var myAccNo = prompt("what is your acc number?");
    for(i = 0; i<= customer.length; i++) {
        if (myAccNo === customer.accNo){
           alert("match");
            console.log(customer[i]);
    }
}   
}

Comment: I updated answer. You can check it . Use filter rather than for loop for searching

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: why console is showing this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at displayMyAcc

Comment: It says there is no place like you said. You may wrote wrong id name there . Can you share your that part of code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215192/discussion-between-mamata-and-pc-coder).

Comment: function displayMyAcc(){ 
  var myAccNo = prompt("what is your acc number?");
  document.getElementById("showMyAcc").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(customer.filter(x=>x.accNo==myAccNo)[0]);
}

Comment: Why use myAccNo[0] ?

Comment: Because filter returns array . That is why I take 0 element.

Comment: Okay ,got it .Thanks!